# Hartshorne chapter II Example 6.11.4: why the singularity deduces a contradiction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In this example, $X=V_+(X^3-Y^2Z)\subset \mathbb P_k^2$, and $Z=(0,0,1)$. In the end of the first paragraph of page 143, he claims that since $Z$ is a singular point, $\mathcal O_{X,Z}$ won't dominate any DVR in $\mathbb P_k^1$. But why? Could you provide a detailed explanation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall theorem I.6.1A:

> **Theorem**: Let $K$ be a field. A local ring $R$ contained in $K$ is a valuation ring if and only if it is a maximal element of the set of local rings contained in $K$, with respect to the relation of domination. Every local ring contained in $K$ is dominated by some valuation ring of $K$.

If $\mathcal{O}_{X,Z}$ dominates a DVR $R\subset k(t)$, then by the theorem we must have $\mathcal{O}_{X,Z}=R$ since $R$ is maximal with respect to the relation of dominantion. But this says $\mathcal{O}_{X,Z}$ is a DVR, which we know is equivalent to $Z$ being a regular point of $X$, which it is not.